# Issue with iFrame Element not re-sizing within container

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I am working on a small VA project and I am attempting to pull stats from another website. The only way I have been able to find out how to do this, is by using an iFrame with the clip function.

Website is: [NWGlobalVA.com](http://NWGlobalVA.com)

Now the Issue I am having is if you go to the main page and re-size the browser in anyway it pushes behind the map element. I have tried everything in my knowledge and research to make it re-size with the container.

Below is the code I use with the iFrame and CSS to do the clipping. Any help would be much more appreciated then you will understand. I have been trying to do this for a couple days now. Ideally I would rather just get the information once every 15 minutes and pass it to my database. However on the website none of the tables are defined and I would know how to go about that.

```
<style>   
.iframeb {   
    position: absolute;   
    left:-384px;   
    right:0px;   
    top: -145px;   
    clip: rect(190px, 625px, 350px, 400px);   
}</style> 


<iframe width="890" height="1900" src="http://fscloud-infotool.de/index.php?page=vasystem&subpage=vadetails&id=10277" class="iframeb" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I deal with iframe size is with javascript (jquery):

I calculated the original iframe aspect ratio by taking the width/height. So in your case: 890/1900.

```
<script>
function size_iFrame()
{
    // If the width and height of the iframe are set 
    // as attributes (<iframe width='890' height='1900'>), 
    // you can have the js calculate it for you.
    // aspect= $('iframe').attr('width') / $('iframe').attr('height');
    aspect= 0.47; 
    $('iframe').css('width', '100%');
    $('iframe').css('height', $('iframe').width() / aspect);
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    size_iFrame();
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        size_iFrame();
    });
}
</script>
```

This will fit the iframe to the width of its container and give it the same aspect ratio as it initially had.

Edit: To answer your question, i'd call it from the ready callback and setup and window resize callback to call every time the screen size changes. I edited my code above to show this.

Edit2: As @mugé points out, you'll also need to remove your iframe css styling for my method to work.

Comment: Awesome Mark! If I had a bit more reputation I would upvote this answer. I will give this a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the example!

Comment: Hey @Mark, I am curious on how you would execute the above on the iFrame. (I can't get the code Markdown to work...) Would you write it into a function like `<script language="javaScript">
      <!--
      function autoResize(){
       aspect= 0.47; 
       $('iframe').css('width', '100%');
       $('iframe').css('height', $('iframe').width() / aspect);
      }
      //-->
     </script>` and then execute on the iFrame Via. `onLoad="autoResize();` Sorry if my questions are really noobish. I am still learning but very much interested.

Comment: @WhiskeySimulation, I edited my answer to address your question.

Comment: Awesome @mark, you have been a huge help thus far. Another question, I find that without the position: absolute; I can no longer use `clip: rect(190px, 625px, 350px, 400px);` to display just the portion of the page that I want. The entire page displays in the container and actually re-sizes the entire container to go way underneath the map display.

Comment: I see. Well use whatever css works for your specific case. Does my answer work for you?

Comment: you're explanation was perfect and example was very nice, however I was unable to get it to react in the needed way. I am sure I am doing something wrong and it's not your fault. I am going to keep fiddling with it. I really want to get better at this, it's really tough trying to figure it all out though. If you go to the site. http://nwglobalva.com and you can see what I have now on the left hand side and what I used as code using inspect. Ill figure it out eventually, Not looking for other people to do my work. Trying to learn as well :)

Answer (score 1):

In responsive design, I assign the iframe a container sized inside the CSS.  For example,

**CSS**
    .iframe_container {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        width: 89%;  //whatever width you want
    }

You will need to eliminate your .iframeb absolute, right, left positionings, because the container will take care of it all, unless you are talking about the 'List' parameters on top of the map, I would try to use @media to arrange clean lists according to screen sizes for the .iframeb class.

Comment: Can this still be done using `clip: rect(190px, 625px, 350px, 400px);` I am trying to display a specific set of data from the page.

Comment: I am positive that you can use the 'clip' inside  @media just by adjusting their positioning for each clip.

Comment: I saw 'clip:rect' is depreciated and cannot be used with relative positioning.  I found the following on clipping but more masking related, however, surrounding the article, you may find some lead to solving your task [link]https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/  Other than that, I would try tackling by applying table property perhaps combined but (definitely)  @media properties.  Since I only work with Responsive design, @ media is my saving grace in most tacklings.  And still, you can give absolute positioning inside the container that is relative.

Comment: Yeah, I had too many issues with it. I ended up just storing the values to a data base VIA a PHP source scrape. It's probably much cleaner in the long run as long as the source of the site doesn't change too much.